# creating an array containing pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

I'm trying to create an array of pointers in C. Each value of the array should be a pointer to a struct (let's call it struct Type*).

Should i do

```
struct Type* myVariable= malloc(sizeof(struct Type*)*MY_SIZE);
```

or

```
struct Type** myVariable= malloc(sizeof(struct Type*)*MY_SIZE);
```

The second one looks like what i should do when i want to create a two dimensional array, which are an array of pointer, and those pointers are used to create arrays of the wanted type. 
EDIT : But in my case the second dimension size would be only one

The first one looks like a regular array with int* as the contained values type.

How can i pass the good solution to a function (by pointer, not by value because the array may be fairly large) and use it in the fonction ?

Comment: second one.....

Comment: the first creates an array of struct Types, the second is an array struct Type pointers so pick the second, to pass it to a function the function needs to except an argument of type struct Type**, then call your function and pass in myVariable declared the second way

Comment: @Ryan Fitzpatrick : Thank you, i completely forgot the basics... Long time no C :'(

Answer (score 2):

The second one the right solution. However, you'll need to allocate memory for the objects too. Also, make sure to check the value returned by `malloc`.

```
// Allocate memory for the array of pointers.
struct Type** myVariable = malloc(sizeof(struct Type*)*MY_SIZE);
if ( myVariable == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error
   exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < MY_SIZE; ++i )
{
   // Allocate memory for the array of objects.
   myVariable[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Type)*THE_SIZE_IN_THE_OTHER_DIMENSION);
   if ( myVariable[i] == NULL )
   {
      // Free everything that was allocated so far
      for (int j = 0; j < i-1; ++j )
      {
         free(myVariable[j]);
      }
      free(myVariable);

      // Exit the program.
      exit(1);
   }
}
```

However, if `THE_SIZE_IN_THE_OTHER_DIMENSION` is going to be `1`, you are better off using your first approach.

```
struct Type* myVariable = malloc(sizeof(struct Type)*MY_SIZE);
                                     // ^^^^^^^^^^^ Drop the *
if ( myVariable == NULL )
{
   // Deal with error
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: So if there is a size 1 in the other dimension, i just want one pointer pointing to one value in each myVariable[i], i just do myVariable[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Type)); right ? Then can i manipulate myVariable content with  just myVariable[i] and not myVariable[i][j] (since j would always value 0 in my case)

Comment: @Csi, "yes" to the first question, "no" to the second question. When the second dimension is 1, you need to use `myVariable[i][0]` or `*myVariable[i]`.

Comment: If the second dimension is `1`, you are better off using the first approach from your question. In that case, you can use `myVariable[i]` to access the object.

Comment: @R Sahu The first one, struct Type* myVariable= malloc(sizeof(struct Type*)*MY_SIZE); right ? So it wasn't a random stupid idea after all

Comment: @Csi, that is correct. No, it wasn't a random stupid idea.

Comment: @Csi, notice the minor but very significant change in my answer. You need to use `sizeof(struct Type)` not `sizeof(struct Type*)`.

Comment: @R Sahu how `struct Type* myVariable= malloc(sizeof(struct Type)*MY_SIZE);` is different from creating an array of struct Type ? I want pointers of struct Type in my array.

Comment: If the size is known at compile time, it is better to use an array. It removes the hassles of allocating memory using `malloc`, adding error checking code, and then using `free` to deallocate the memory. The only time you cannot use an array, even when the size is known at compile time, is if the size is too large for stack memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98031/discussion-between-csi-and-r-sahu).

Comment: A couple of problems with the posted answer: 1) init the first malloc'd area to all NULLs 2) when malloc of individual struct fails, loop to pass malloc'd structs to free() then pass the original malloc'd pointer to free().   Otherwise the code will leak memory

Comment: @user3629249, good call on the error handling part. I don't think it is necessary to init the first `malloc`ed memory to `NULL`. They are being initialized using subsequent `malloc` calls.

Comment: @RSahu, the init of the first malloc'd array is so the (eventual) calls to free(), especially if there is a malloc() error, is so a simple loop will work to pass every pointer to free(), without having to also keep a count of how many successful calls to malloc() were performed

Comment: @user3629249, that information is already available as part of allocating memory in the second loop. There is no need of an additional bookkeeping counter.

Answer (score 0):

Neither!

Use an idiom that reduces work and errors

```
pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * Number_of_elements);
```

Or in OP's case "to create an array of pointers in C"

```
#define ARRAY_N 100
struct Type **myVariable = malloc(sizeof *myVariable * N);
if (myVariable == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemmory();
```

Now set those pointers to some value

```
#define M 50
size_t i;
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  myVariable[i] = malloc(sizeof *(myVariable[i]) * M);
  if (myVariable[i] == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemmory();

  for (size_t m = 0; m<M; m++) {
    // Initialize the fields of 
    myVariable[i][m].start = 0;
    myVariable[i][m].value = 0.0;
    myVariable[i][m].set = NULL;
  }
}
```